# Malformed request when creating billing plan

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

So I a using the node paypal-rest-sdk module and I'm trying to create a billing plan. Using the documentation [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans#plan_create_request) I made this JSON:

`const billingPlanAttributes = {
  name: 'Subscription',
  description: 'Monthly subscription plan',
  type: 'INFINITE',
  payment_definitions: [{
    name: 'Regular monthly infinite payments',
    type: 'REGULAR',
    frequency_interval: '1',
    frequency: 'MONTH',
    cycles: '0',
    amount: {
      currency: 'USD',
      amount: '4.99',
    },
  }],
  merchant_preferences: {
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/subscribe/cancel',
    return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/subscribe/return',
    auto_bill_amount: 'YES',
  },
};`

But when using the `paypal.billingPlan.create(...` function I get the error `'MALFORMED_REQUEST', 'Incoming JSON request does not map to API request'`. So I guess my JSON is not in the correct format or I'm missing something that is need.

The documentation has a `charge_models` key but it does not mention that it is required unlike other keys.

If you can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Edit: changed the return url and cancel url to include the full domain but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

There could be more to this, but I noticed one thing wrong with your JSON.  Remove commas for items last in a list. After 'amount' and 'merchant_preferences'.  JSON is picky.

Comment: I removed the commas but still getting the same error. You seem to be right about there being more to this. I am using eslint which was giving me warnings about adding commas at the end which is why I had them.

Comment: Hmm.  Looks like I missed some commas; after 'auto_bill_amount' and the other 'amount'.  But assuming you already got those, I believe the strings need to be in double quotes.  Both key and value.

Comment: Yes removed them commas also. Added double quotes but still same error. Tried with the JSON provided in the example and it seemed to work so I guess I'm missing something that is required.

Comment: So I ended up just copying the example and changing the values to what I needed. I also formatted it to how eslint suggests JSON and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

late answer, I know, but ran in exactly the same issue than you.

In the create function of the billing plan

```
public function create($apiContext = null, $restCall = null)
{
    $payLoad = $this->toJSON();
    $json = self::executeCall(
        "/v1/payments/billing-plans/",
        "POST",
        $payLoad,
        null,
        $apiContext,
        $restCall
    );
    $this->fromJson($json);
    return $this;
}
```

I found out, that the `toJSON` method always returned `false`. Why the hell!?!

I did the same as you did and copied the complete sample code into my code. Then it worked as expected. Now I checked, what the difference was in to my code. 
I realized, that I used an umlauts (ä,ü,ö) in the name and description of the billing plan. I changed the umlauts to

```
'ä' => 'ae', 
'ö' => 'oe' 
'ü' => 'ue'
```

Then it worked fine! Maybe someone else is running in this issue, too.